# Displaying accents in PHP on data pulled from MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding, diacritics

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something basic, but I can't figure out what it is.  Everything should be default characterset (I haven't specified or changed anything) which I assume is Latin1.  This should be fine as all the characters I need are in Latin1 (most questions seem directed at changing charset to utf-8).

I used copy and paste from an HTML page with charset=iso-8859-1 to insert some letters with acutes and umlauts into a MYSQL database, which shows up fine when selected from the commandline.  However well I select these in a PHP script and display with iso-8859-1 as the browser encoding, they show up as commas or apostrophes only.

ä = „
ö = ”
é = ‚
á =   (a blank)

If I just copy and paste these vowels below the actual php tags, they display correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Try using htmlentities()

I think that worked for me in the past.

Comment: For some reason, this does not change anything.  If the database is latin1, the page is latin1, the php is latin1 where is the problem occuring?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that where you're displaying your data has a `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />` and that your MySQL table is set accordingly. Mine is set to `MyISAM, latin1--cp1252 West European, latin1_spanish_ci` and it solved my problems!

(I had imported an Excel sheet into MySQL using Navicat, and the sheet contained special characters like "á" and such.)